# Meaning of Smooth Dynamical System?

Tags: terminology, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

What does [smooth dynamical system](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=smooth+dynamical+system) mean? It is the title of a paper that I am supposed to read in non-linear systems.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the specific paper? The Wikipedia article on [dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) states that smooth can mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: Smooth usually means that the function is [continuously differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many dynamical systems involve recursive sequences of simple functions, $f(f(f(...f(x))))$ which are iterated *n* times to lead to some discrete iteration sequence (a Picard sequence) with often tractable properties. It is possible however, to analytically continue the discrete iteration index *n* to a continuous non integer one, fractional, infinitesimal, or negative, through the miracle of [functional conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Conjugacy) and to produce [continuous orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system#Basic_definitions), $f_t(x)$, whose velocity and continuous phase-space trajectories may be monitored.

The theory that makes this possible is the celebrated [Schröder's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation)  (1870) which allows easy calculation of functional square (and higher) roots, and renormalization trajectories, since it turns out that the original Gell-Mann-Low Renormalization Group equation (1954) is, in fact, this very equation of Schröder, [RG](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.83.065019).

Typically, you use it, e.g.,  to extend the  Beverton-Holt map $f(x)=x/(2−x)$  to its continuous iterate 
$$f_t(x)=\frac{x}{2^t + x(1-2^t)}   ~,$$
where *f(x)* is the above for [*t*=1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/48/485208). The resulting evolution surface is thus ***smooth***.

On a logarithmic scale, such iteration flows might well be already familiar to you from the [nesting property of Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function), $T_m (T_n(x))= T_{mn}(x)$, since  $T_{\exp (t)}(x)=  \cos (e^t \arccos (x))$, in suitable intervals. (Note that for continuous iteration trajectory index *t* these functions are not polynomials anymore, in general, as they are for integer values of exp*t*.)

Answer (score 1):

A dynamical system is a system that evolves by a rule over time. As opposed to modeling a system with a PDE, the system is modeled by some type of iterated function, $f^t(x)$. Smooth implies that the function being iterated is differentiable, so we are not talking about an iterated system like cellular automata.

Answer (score 0):

A system is  called as smooth dynamical system when, the function is continuous in its domain &  the nth order derivative for the system exists.All dynamical systems, are modeled mathematically  evolving on Smooth manifolds $C^n$ where n belongs to natural numbers& they should have a one to one correspondence with the members of the set.